# Let $f_n(x) =\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$ and what function does this sequence converge to?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f_n(x) =\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$

I think that this sequence of function converges to 0.

And compute $f'_n(x)$ and find all values of $x$ for which $f'(x)=\lim f'_n(x)$

I found $f'_n(x)=\left(\frac{1-nx^2}{1+nx^2}\right)^2$  then it seems like that $\lim f'_n(x)=0$ for all $x$ except $x=0$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Your primes are not showing.

Comment: How come you asked 50 questions on Math SE but don't know the basics of formatting here?

Comment: A certain amount of guessing is necessary, but it seems right.

Comment: Only square the denominator, not the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}\le \frac{x}{nx^2}=\frac{1}{nx}$, $x\not= 0$