# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{f_n}(x) = \frac{x}{n^\alpha(1+nx^2)}$ conv. uniformly over any interval $[a,b]$ where $\alpha>1/2$

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt included finding the maximum of the sequence of functions to find the maximum of the function and then using the Wierstrauss $M$-Test. However, I couldn't find a suitable $M$ that worked for comparison to the original function. I looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120317/show-that-the-sequence-of-functions-f-nx-fracx1nx2-converges-unifor) very similar problem but I am not sure it would work for this version with an exponent alpha greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Here is my proof:

WTS: For every $\epsilon$ greater than 0, $\exists M_\epsilon.\mid{f(x)} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty{f_n}(x)\mid\leq \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty{f_n}(x)\mid \leq M_\epsilon$ where the $M$ is an arbitrary function chosen by finding the maximum of the given sequence.

$\mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^\alpha (1+nx^2)}\mid  \leq  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mid \frac{1}{n^\alpha} \mid$. This is as far as I got since when $\alpha = 1$ the series diverges. I eventually would like to come to the conclusion that

$\mid \sup_{x\in R[a,b]}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{f_n} \mid  \leq  \sup_{x\in R[a,b]}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mid{f_n}\mid < M_\epsilon$

Comment: The equation in the title does not make sense. Is it meant that $f_n$ should be defined by the rational function to the right of it?

Comment: Yes. I've been continuously editing this question. Thank you for pointing out that error.

Comment: It's a series, not a sequence.